# echo for loop into string

Tags: php, variables, for-loop

I have a for loop that I want to be able to echo the results into a string. How can this be done? It only echos the last run of the loop into my variable to be used outside of the loop.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $numItem; $i++) {
            extract($cartContent[$i]);

        $pricebands = array("1"=>"$pd_price1","2"=>"$pd_price2","3"=>"$pd_price3","4"=>"$pd_price4","5"=>"$pd_price5","6"=>"$pd_price6");
        if(isset($loggedInfo['price'])){
            $priceToShow = $pricebands[$loggedInfo['price']];
        } else {
            $priceToShow = $pricebands[1];
        }
            $productUrl = "index.php?c=$cat_id&p=$pd_id";
            $subTotal += $priceToShow * $ct_qty;
            $pd_name;
            $ct_qty;
            $productList = "L_NAME".$i."=".$pd_name."&L_AMT".$i."=".$priceToShow."&L_QTY".$i."=".$ct_qty."&";   
        }
        $amount = $subTotal;           
    }
```

and the variable to put the $productList into

```
   $nvpstr="&PAYMENTACTION=$paymentType&AMT=$amount&".trim($productList)."CREDITCARDTYPE=$creditCardType&ACCT=$creditCardNumber&EXPDATE=".$padDateMonth.$expDateYear."&CVV2=$cvv2Number&FIRSTNAME=$firstName&LASTNAME=$lastName&STREET=$address1&CITY=$city&STATE=$state&ZIP=$zip&COUNTRYCODE=$countryCode&CURRENCYCODE=$currencyCode";
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're resetting $productList each time you loop. You want to add to it, not set it:

```
$productList .= 'new stuff...';
```

Before the loop, set the variable to an empty string to which you will add more characters:

```
$productList = '';
```

Comment: thanks, I put the empty variable outside the loop before you posted that haha, Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

String Concatination or implode.

I am a little confussed at to the exact strings you want joined, there are no echo's.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $numItem; $i++) {
        extract($cartContent[$i]);

    $pricebands = array("1"=>"$pd_price1","2"=>"$pd_price2","3"=>"$pd_price3","4"=>"$pd_price4","5"=>"$pd_price5","6"=>"$pd_price6");
    if(isset($loggedInfo['price'])){
        $priceToShow = $pricebands[$loggedInfo['price']];
    } else {
        $priceToShow = $pricebands[1];
    }
        $productUrl = "index.php?c=$cat_id&p=$pd_id";
        $subTotal += $priceToShow * $ct_qty;
        $pd_name;
        $ct_qty;
        $productList .= "L_NAME".$i."=".$pd_name."&L_AMT".$i."=".$priceToShow."&L_QTY".$i."=".$ct_qty."&";   
    }
    $amount = $subTotal;           
}
```